# Send command doesn't send keys in autoit script

Tags: autoit

I started writing code like this using AutoIT V3

```
$file = "G:\FullSetup800203.exe"

ShellExecuteWait($file)

Sleep(75000)

WinWaitActive("M1 Setup")

Send("!n")
```

It all works but send command doesn't work.

I am using windows 7 64-bit machine.

Comment: If the resulting window that is created from opening the file is "M1 Setup", you don't need the Sleep() function as WinWaitActive() is already going to 'Sleep' the script until the file is open.

Answer (score 3):

I may be wrong, but it looks to me as though you are using `ShellExecuteWait` when you don't actually want to `Wait`.

What is happening right now is that you are running the file and WAITING for it to close, once the process is exitted then you sleep for another 75 seconds before waiting for some window to be active and then sending the characters. Is that what you intended?

The send command always sends the keys. To say it "doesn't work" is not right, it just do what you expected it to.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = "G:\FullSetup800203.exe"

ShellExecute($file)

Sleep(75000)

WinWaitActive("M1 Setup")

Send("!{n}")
```

try that.

Answer (score 0):

After long searching why the script works on Windows XP and not on Windows 7 64 bit I discovered the cause.
On Windows 7 the AutoIt script has to run as Administrator to send keystrokes and access controls for some applications.

Answer (score 0):

add Administrator to the opening of cmd.exe
ControlSend("Administrator: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe", "", "", "cd C:\Program Files (x86)\thefile")@SW_SHOW)